# Inkscape Pull Things inward

Tags: inkscape

Does anyone now how in inkscape how to pull things sort of inward? As an example, I am trying to take the following image ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Annular_(PSF).svg)) and pull the yellow teeth more towards the middle so text can fit in.

Sample image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your actual object, you might be able to select the inner points with the **Edit Paths by Nodes** tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>) and then click the **Show Transformation Handles for Selected Nodes** button in the upper right. Then you can scale those points smaller without affecting the outer ring. The geometry might get thrown off a bit if the gears are too close together...
[image: menu for handles]

**Edit:** You can either select the inner teeth by lassoing while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to stretch them out... 
Or it is easier to break the paths apart and then just select the *outer* circle and make it bigger... Both results are shown below...

[image: teeth moving in]
[image: Circle moving out]

Comment: I would like to bet able to do this with symmetry, and there are a large number of teeth.

Comment: You can get symmetry by holding `Shift` and `Control` as noted in @thomasrutter's answer. Is it this exact image that you want to modify, or something like it?

Comment: Actually, I was using it as the base for another image. (Do not worry, it is public domain.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it.

1. Separate the yellow shape into its two disconnected objects using Path -> Break Apart.

   At this point it may become harder to see the objects so you can switch to wireframe mode with `Ctrl`+`Numpad5` twice.
2. Deselect everything then select only the teeth, not the surrounding circle.
3. Shrink this symmetrically and from the centre by dragging one of its corner points while holding `Shift` and `Ctrl`.
4. Combine the two objects again by selecting them both and going to Path -> Exclusion.